# How to reset scanf()

Tags: c, scanf

How do you reset `scanf()` to read the beginning of the text without the use of `fopen` or `fclose`.

I have a stage 1 which reads half of the text file and stage 2 requires me reset the `scanf()` to beginning of the text and read it all the way. 
Any tips or guidance is appreciated.
You Guys are the best!

EDIT: The text has ONLY numbers in it and the file is opened via `/myprogram <txt.txt`.

Comment: One does not simply `fseek()` into `stdin`, which `scanf()` implicitly uses. Surely you meant `fscanf()`, and are using a `FILE* fp` other than `stdin`? In this case `fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET)` rewinds to the beginning of the stream, as does the shorter `rewind(fp)`.

Comment: The file is just numbers. Sorry for the ambiguity! This is also an assignment which requires me to not use any character related  commands.

Comment: Perhaps I misread the question. If the text is coming through `stdin` because of redirection, e.g. `./myprogram <somefile.txt`, then I don't know how to restart the file from the beginning.

Comment: @user3386109 Yes thats it ! Its just numbers.I just want it to go back to the start or pretend that it did...

Comment: Well, on my machine `rewind(stdin)` seems to work if `stdin` is connected to a file by redirection, but I'm not sure how portable that is.

Comment: @user3386109 So do I type in stdin or the file name?

Comment: You use `rewind(stdin);`

Comment: That's good! Since Chan already has an answer, feel free to click the check mark next to his answer to finish the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `fseek()` or `rewind()`.

```
rewind(fp);
```

or

```
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

Answer (score 3):

One can use `rewind(FILE *fp)` to reset the position to beginning of the file.